# Output of Print statement is giving as (None, None) result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am trying to print values of two variables in Python. My question is when I am trying to print the values in this way like print(a),print(b) in Jupyter notebook, I am getting the values of the variables but the output is also giving a tuple type of result which is giving as (None,None). I want to know why it is giving that (None,None) output. I should have got result like (value1,value2). Someone please advise. Also, please let me know how to the result in tuple format like (2,5) where a=2,b=5. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxgn0.png)

Comment: Please don't bump your question by commenting on it. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Python does that when the type of the value is a *set* or *list* data type.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a side effect of the command line.  You wouldn't see this if you run a program.  If you just type an expression in a command line:

```
>>> 3
3
```

Python shows you the result of that expression.  If the expression returns None, Python shows you nothing. So:

```
>>> time.sleep(3)
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>>
```

`time.sleep` returns `None`, so you see nothing.  You see the side effect of the print statement, but because the print statement returned `None`, it shows you nothing else.  But when you do:

```
>>> print(a),print(b)
2
5
(None,None)
>>>
```

Both print statements return None, and because you've used a comma, the result of that expression is a tuple containing two None values.  So, you see the side effect of the print statements, and because your expression (`(None,None)`) is not exactly the same as `None`, Python prints it for you.

The comma operator is NOT the right way to separate multiple statements, like you do in C.  In Python, the comma operator builds tuples.  If you want to separate multiple statements on a line, use semi-colon:

```
>>> print(a);print(b)
2
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of Jupyter called autocall. There is some documentation on it here:
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall

To split up your call either ";" or print((a,b)). Not sure what you are trying to achieve.